# In SQL Server, table add a column.　causing view error

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

In SQL Server, create a view using two tables. One of tables used `*` in view.

Then I add a column to the table. This is now causing view error.

Must rebuild the view to solve this problem.

If this table is used a lot of views, how to identify relevant views and rebuild them?

There are a number of ways?

Thank you!

Test environment: SQL Server 2008

Test SQL:

```
 if exists(select * from sys.objects where name='tblTestA' and type='u')
DROP TABLE  tblTestA

create table tblTestA(Part varchar(10),Qty int)
insert into tblTestA values('A',10)
insert into tblTestA values('B',20)
go

if exists(select * from sys.objects where name='tblTestB' and type='u')
    DROP TABLE  tblTestB
GO

create table tblTestB(Part varchar(10),Price decimal(9,4))
GO

insert into tblTestB values('A',1.1)
insert into tblTestB values('B',2.2)
GO

if exists(select * from sys.objects where name='v_test' and type='v')
    DROP VIEW  v_test
go

create View v_test
as
  select a.*,b.Price
  from tblTestA a, tblTestB b 
  where a.Part=b.Part
go
```

Execute:

```
select * from v_test 
go
```

result:

```
Part Qty Price
A   10  1.1000
B   20  2.2000
```

Add a column

```
alter table tblTestA add Remark nvarchar(200) not null default('test')
go
```

Execute:

```
select * from v_test 
go
```

Result:

```
Part Qty Price
A   10  test
B   20  test
```

Comment: you could try searching the view definitions for the table that has been altered, stackoverflow.com/questions/4765323/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-view-definition-from-a-sql-server-using-plain-ado

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago!)

Comment: Thank you! Good habits: select a.*,b.Price  from tblTestA a inner join tblTestB b   on  a.Part=b.Part ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can figure out related views by using SQL Server Management Studio.

You need to select the table in SSMS and then right click it.  Select `View Dependencies`.

In this picture the table is `CompanyCategoryXref` (blue arrow).  The dependent view in this case is `CompanyCategory` (red arrow).  You can also see that the selected item `CompanyCategory` is of object type `View` (yellow circle).

[image: SSMS Dependency]

Comment: According to you tips I find all Views. And then What ? One by one  manually execute view script ?

Comment: @dream - you could have a script that updates the views, as suggested in the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

If you create your view `WITH SCHEMABINDING`, you won't encounter this problem.  For your *old* views ;-) you can use [sp_refreshview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821.aspx).

To find which views rely on which tables, you *could* use the GUI, but that doesn't scale very well.  Instead, I recommend you use the system-management views e.g. [sys.sql_expression_dependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677315.aspx).  That lets you iterate over the dependent views and issue `exec sp_refreshview` for each one.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem - our solution has to come up with a SQL script to refresh all views. We run this script after every batch of update scripts that modify the database structure - this ensures that all views are up to date and functioning.

This is the T-SQL code:

```
DECLARE @viewname sysname
DECLARE @counter INT

SET @counter = 1

DECLARE viewname_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT v.[name] 
    FROM sys.views v
    INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules m ON v.object_id = m.object_id
    WHERE m.is_schema_bound = 0  -- only refresh non-schemabound views

OPEN viewname_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM viewname_cursor INTO @viewname

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT CAST(@counter AS varchar(3)) + '. Refreshed view ' + @viewname

    EXEC sp_refreshview @viewname   -- refresh the view in question

    SET @counter = @counter + 1

    FETCH NEXT FROM viewname_cursor INTO @viewname
END

CLOSE viewname_cursor
DEALLOCATE viewname_cursor
GO
```